# Only the original Thread error

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am baffled by this error -

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I have a class, which is called within a runnable/thread block in the UI. No attempt - as far as I can see ??? - is made to manipulate the UI within that runnable, or the class it calls, as below.....

```
public class MonthSort {
Handler handler;
int imageWidth;
List<PhotoData> photoList;
public MonthSort(Handler handler2, int width, List<PhotoData> pList) {
    photoList = new ArrayList<PhotoData>();
    photoList = pList;
    imageWidth = width;
    handler = handler2;
}

public void sortFiles()
{
    int month, photoCount;
    File fileName = new File("");
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        month = i + 1;
        photoCount = 0;
        for (PhotoData pd : photoList) {
            if(month == pd.month)
            {
                if(photoCount == 0)
                    fileName = pd.fileName;
                photoCount++;
            }
        }
        if(photoCount != 0)
        {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("filename", fileName.toString());
            bundle.putInt("month", month);
            bundle.putInt("count", photoCount);
            byte[] thumbNail = getThumbnail(fileName, imageWidth);
            bundle.putByteArray("thumbnail", thumbNail);
            msg.setData(bundle);
            handler.dispatchMessage(msg);

        }
    }
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("end", true);
    msg.setData(bundle);
    handler.dispatchMessage(msg);
}

private byte[] getThumbnail(File file, int size)
{
    /** The object of this code is to reduce the bitmap for thumbnail display,
     * Not just to reduce dimensions, but to reduce the physical size of the 
     * bitmap ready, so that several bitmaps can remain in memory without 
     * an outOfMemoryException error.*/
    byte[] thumbnail;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
            file.toString(), options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(
            options, imageWidth, imageWidth);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.toString(),
            options);
     /*now the size of the Bitmap is manageable, we set about sizing the 
     * thumbnail correctly, preserving the Aspect Ratio */

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = imageWidth;
    int thumbHeight = REQUIRED_SIZE, thumbWidth = REQUIRED_SIZE;
    float ratio = (float) bitmap.getWidth() // Work out the aspect ratio.
            / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
    if (ratio == 1) {
        thumbHeight = REQUIRED_SIZE;
        thumbWidth = REQUIRED_SIZE;
    } else if (ratio < 1) {
        thumbHeight = REQUIRED_SIZE;
        thumbWidth = (int) ((float) REQUIRED_SIZE * (float) ratio);
    } else {
        thumbWidth = REQUIRED_SIZE;
        thumbHeight = (int) ((float) REQUIRED_SIZE / (float) ratio);
    }
    Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmap, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap2.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, out); // Compress the bitmap   
        thumbnail = out.toByteArray();
        out.close(); // close the out stream.
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        thumbnail = new byte[1];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        thumbnail = new byte[1];
    }
    return thumbnail;
}

private int calculateInSampleSize(Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
    {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

The main thread has the handler at the top (See code below - Just the handler code for brevity) as normal, and uses the notifyDataSetChanged() method of a custom adapter (code included)...

```
public class MonthActivity extends Activity {
List<PhotoData> photoList;
static List<MonthData> photos;
int imageWidth;
GridView photoGrid;
static ImageAdapter2 iAdapter2;
static int year;
Thread monthSortThread;

static Handler handler2 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();  // Get the message sent to the Handler.
        boolean ended = bundle.getBoolean("end");
        if(ended)
        {
            iAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FINISHED !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else
        {
            MonthData md = new MonthData();
            md.monthValue = bundle.getInt("month");
            md.monthString = getMonthString(md.monthValue);
            Log.d("Debug", md.monthString + " " + String.valueOf(year));
            md.count = bundle.getInt("count");
            byte[] tn = bundle.getByteArray("thumbnail");
            md.thumbnail =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tn, 0, tn.length);
            photos.add(md);
            iAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

(Adapter code)

```
public class ImageAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter{
List<MonthData> photos;
Context context;
int year, imageWidth;
public ImageAdapter2 (Context ct, List<MonthData> pList, int yr, int i) {
    photos = new ArrayList<MonthData>();
    photos = pList;
    context = ct;
    year = yr;
    imageWidth = i;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return photos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View myView = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        myView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);
    } else
    {
        myView = convertView;
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.photoText);
    if(year == 0)
    {
        int count = photos.get(position).count;
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    } else
    {
        int count = photos.get(position).count;
        String month = photos.get(position).monthString;
        String yearString = String.valueOf(year);
        tv.setText(month + " " + yearString + " (" + String.valueOf(count) + ")");
    }
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.photoViewGridCell);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    iv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
    iv.setMaxHeight(imageWidth);
    iv.setMaxWidth(imageWidth);
    iv.setImageBitmap(photos.get(position).thumbnail);
    return myView;
}
```

}

Please note that MonthActivity is called, via an Intent, on selecting a Custom View (specifically a collection of views, in a separate xml layout file) ImageAdapter2 is just a small variation on a similar Adapter used for the "starting" activity, with a slightly different custom view.

Also, ImageAdapter2 is properly "connected" to the Layout required, and initiated in the onCreate() method, it even successfully runs the constructor, but despite having several different breakpoints within the adapter's getView method none of them are ever reached when debugging... very frustrating.. any ideas ?

Comment: You might be trying to access the View from another thread.....

Comment: Post the stack trace too.

Answer (score 1):

Put your Runnable in runOnUiThread method when you call it.

Comment: Thanks. That's sorted it !